# Proc sql last not empty field

Tags: sas

Good time of the day to anyone.

Here is my case I need to solve:

I have some table table1 with columns: `field, stage1 - stage10.`
Is it possible to using `PROC SQL` statement `CREATE TABLE` to create table2  with field: `field1, final_stage` where final stage is the last NOT EMPTY FIELD from array stage1 - stage10. Thank you;

I know how to do it using data step:

```
data table2 (keep field1 final_stage);
set table1;
array final_stage[10] stage1-stage10;
do i=1 to 10;
If final_stage[i] ^= "" then final_stage=final_stage[i];run;
```

Comment: the above is missing an `end;` statement to make it a working example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try reversing the order and make use of the `coalescec` function as follows:

```
proc sql;
create table table2 as
  select field1
    ,coalescec(stage10,stage9,stage8,stage7,stage6
      ,stage5,stage4,stage3,stage2,stage1) as final_stage
  from table1;
```

The `coalescec` function resolves to the first non-missing character value in the list (see [documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002518268.htm)).